# Deploying to FTP/Web Deploy In Visual Studio 2015

Tags: ftp, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-web-deploy

I cannot figure out a way to publish a web project in Visual Studio 2015 CTP using web deploy or FTP. In the Publish wizard, there are only options for Azure, Import and File System. In Visual Studio 2013, there is a Custom option where you can specify the connection settings and choose between Web Deploy, Web Deploy Package, FTP and Filesystem.

I tried moving over the publish profile from my Visual Studio 2013 project by putting it in the Properties-->PublishProfiles folder, and then it behaved like Visual Studio 2013, but would not publish (failed to connect to remote host) with the same settings that publish fine in 2013.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Web Deploy 3.6 beta supports the new content models in ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET vNext) and I guess that the VS 2015 Web-Deploy client doesn't support it yet. (28 April 2015)

[This blog post](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/11/web-deploy-3-6-beta-released/) gives some command-line options for using a publish profile. I'm in a new environment that isn't set up for web-deploy yet, so I haven't tried it myself. (I did a file-system publish to test against my local IIS.)

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same issue. It seems that, at the time of writing, the FTP publish target isn’t available yet: I guess that’s most likely because the Web Development Tools are still in release candidate / preview phase, so the GUI still has some missing features.

Luckily enough the issue can be easily solved with the following workaround.

If you don't see the FTP option, choose File System instead and go ahead. When prompted for a **Target Location**, insert the FTP Server URL and go ahead.

The remaining steps won’t change, so you can complete the wizard that will be saved into a ProfileName.pubxml file.

Once done, open that file and apply the following changes:

1. Locate the `<WebPublishMethod>` element and change its value from `FileSystem` to `FTP`.
2. Locate the `<UsePowerShell>` element and entirely remove it.

Right after doing that, *right-click* to the project’s root node, select **Publish** and re-open your *Publish Profile* via the *Publish Profile Wizard* in edit mode: all the FTP options (*Server*, *Site Path*, *Passive Mode*, *Username*, *Password*) will now be available.